# How to create a file with common modules for Node?

Tags: webpack

First of all my target is not browser env, but Node.

I have three top React components in separate files. They use (require) other other components:

```
Component1.js
    React, ReactIntl
Component2.js
    React, ReactIntl, ComponentFoo
Component2.js,
    React, ReactIntl, ReactToolbox/Dropdown

// Let's say they all quite similar:

const React = require('react');
const ReactIntl = require('react-intl');
const ComponentFoo = require('./ComponentFoo');

const Component1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentFoo />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Component1;
```

It means that EVERY ONE of them requires at least React. I want Webpack to move React and other common modules that my three components use to another file. With that it has to compile my three components in that way so they know from where to require React and other common components:

```
commonModules.js
    React, ReactIntl, ReactToolbox/Dropdown, ComponentFoo, etc...

Component1.js
Component2.js
Component2.js
```

I want to require `Component1` on server-side and it already knows from where to require everything it depends on:

```
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const Component1 = require('./../../path/to/compile/component/to/Component1');

const Component1HTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Component1, {
    data: data
}));
```

How do I configure Webpack so that it can approach it? My current config is as follows and it doesn't work. I use `CommonsChunkPlugin` but how to set it up? I already set `target: 'node'` and `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: process.cwd(),
    entry: {
        'path/to/compile/component/to/Component1': './path/from/Component1.js',
        'path/to/compile/component/to/Component2': './path/from/Component2.js',
        'path/to/compile/component/to/Component3': './path/from/Component3.js',
    },
    debug: false,
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: './',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/i,
                loaders: [
                    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&minimize&localIdentName=[local]_[hash:3]',
                    'sass?includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib"),
                    'toolbox'
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    toolbox: {theme: '_theme.scss'},
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.react', '.scss', '.json'],
    },
    devtool: "eval",
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["commons"],
            filename: "assets/js/react/prod/[name].js",
            minChunks: 2,
            children: true,
        }),
    ],
    target: 'node',
};
```